# How to generate emoji unicode like "\uD83D\uDE02" when i got is "U+1F602"?

Tags: java, unicode, emoji

I'm currently creating something like emoji-keyboard in Android that will show list of emoticon

I don't want to use image, so I need Unicode character for emoji in Java source code to show emoticon in String output.

For example

Unicode Name:   FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY 
C/C++/Java source code: `"\uD83D\uDE02"`
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f602/index.htm

I need Java Unicode like this `"\uD83D\uDE02"` because when I output Label with

```
Label.setText("\uD83D\uDE02");`
```

it works and shows `FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY`

I've already googled this and found [this list](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), I just don't understand how `\uD83D\uDE02` was generated.

Comment: try this https://github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji

Comment: Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510006/remove-and-other-such-emojis-images-signs-from-java-string/49574947#49574947) that has some discussion about emoji and Java.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), before posting your next question here.

Comment: yes, i've tried this code,  github.com/hani-momanii/SuperNova-Emoji , but it was : Based on Hieu Rocker's library Emojicon Github.
and : Emojicon is using emojis graphics from emoji-cheat-sheet.com.

it still using an png emoji images..

Comment: U+1f602 is correct Unicode code. The other two are just surrogate representation (I assume UCS2, which do not know about surrogates, because UTF16 should give the correct value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`U+1F602` is an unicode codepoint, and Java can read these.

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(0x1F602).toString());
```

If you really need to convert it to the other kind of unicode scapes, you can iterate through all the chars, and write those hex codes to the output:

```
for(char c : new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(0x1F602).toString().toCharArray()) {
    System.out.print("\\u" + String.valueOf(Integer.toHexString(c)));
}
System.out.println();
```