# Java String length not working properly

Tags: java, string, string-length

I isolated my original problem in this class. It is returning `2 2`. The first time I executed this code I got `1 1`, I'm going crazy, I don't understand this behavior

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test("‎A");
    }


    public static void test(String cadena) {
        System.out.println(cadena.length());
        System.out.println("‎A".length());
    }

}
```

Comment: You have a non-printable character before the letter. See [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZjD8.png)

Comment: This is not "returning" anything (which it should not, as the return type is `void`).

Comment: Do this: `for (char c : cadena.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.printf("char: %d, %s%n", (int) c, c);
        }`

Comment: What do you mean? Both System.out.println should print 1

Comment: Please do the test that I suggest. Your `"A"` has another invisible char in it.

Comment: @Victor check the image. You have two characters. even if you see just one. That's what "non printable character" means: you don't see it, but it's there. The output is correct.

Comment: You can have any number of non-printable characters in a String.  e.g. `\u202e` is a zero-width character which causes all the characters after it to be printed backwords, even more "fun" is you can use it in variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Your `"‎A"` is actually a sequence of two code points, an unprintable one followed by a capital A letter.

```
"‎A".codePoints().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Will print:

```
8206
65
```

8206 is the [Unicode Character 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK' (U+200E)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) character.

Comment: Thank you all. Do you know how remove all characters but the letter. I have tried this without success : replaceAll("\\s", "");

Comment: If you need to cleanup input data use a whitelist approach, rather than excluding. It's safer. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49516025/1602555).

Answer (score 1):

You have invisible character in the `A`. Both are not the same

```
   System.out.println(cadena.hashCode());
   System.out.println("‎A".hashCode());
   System.out.println("‎A".equals(cadena));
```

Output:

```
65
254451
false
```

Answer (score 0):

This would always print:

```
1
1
```

in normal circumstances.

In your case you seem to have ***some garbage/non printable character*** before `A` in `"A"`.

I suggest you to **delete and re-write** the phrase `"A"`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok from previous answer there is an invisble characrter

```
"‎A".chars() .forEach(i -> System.out.println("there is a char:" + (char)i));
```

Will Print:

```
there is a char:‎
there is a char:A
```

I think someone wants to make a Joke to you with this invisible character.

--Edit--

In Java for removing **A control character** for your String you can use Regex:

```
public static void test(String cadena) {
    System.out.println(cadena.length());
   "‎A".chars() .forEach(i -> System.out.println("there is a char:" + (char)i));
   String b ="‎A".replaceAll("\\p{C}","");
   System.out.println(b.length());
    b.chars() .forEach(i -> System.out.println("there is a char:" + (char)i));
}
```

OutPut:

```
2
there is a char:‎
there is a char:A
1
there is a char:A
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile your code online [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) since I don't have java in my pc, and I see that you have [this character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) (left-to-right mark)

[image]

You can just remove the string and retype it. :)