# How to read/get unicode value for an emoji in Java

Tags: java, unicode, emoji

We are trying to let our application accept emojis. We are trying to limit the emojis to the ones from [this list](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).

So, i am trying to read the unicode value (for example, U+1F600 for ) for emojis - so i can validate that the user entered emoji is from the above list.

can somebody please help me with how to read the unicode value for an emoji? or any other ways i can implement this validation ? using encoded values etc.?

```
        }  

String actualEmojiString = "";
            for(int i=0; i< actualEmojiString.codePointCount(0, actualEmojiString.length()); i++) {
                int codePoint = actualEmojiString.charAt(i);
                if(Character.isSurrogate(actualEmojiString.charAt(i))) {
                    codePoint = Character.toCodePoint(actualEmojiString.charAt(i), actualEmojiString.charAt(i));
                }
                System.out.println( "HexCode value for emoji: [" +  actualEmojiString.charAt(i) + "] is [" +"U+" + Integer.toHexString(codePoint | 0x10000).substring(0) +"]"
                        + "["+"\\u" + Integer.toHexString(codePoint | 0x10000).substring(1) + "]");
```

Output:

```
HexCode value for emoji: [?] is [U+1f03d][\uf03d]
HexCode value for emoji: [?] is [U+190200][\u90200]
```

Comment: Java uses UTF16 strings. Plan accordingly. Also, please look at your question after posting, so that you can click "edit" and fix any formatting mistakes you made: this is not a well formatted question at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are overcomplicating your code by mixing code points and chars. Instead use [`String.codePoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) method:

```
"".codePoints().mapToObj(Integer::toHexString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

will print the unicode values as hex:

```
1f600
1f602
```

This however might not be needed at all because Java supports unicode `String` literals. To check if the text contains an emoji you can simply do:

```
"".contains("");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much!!

Comment: just curious. can i implement this validation any other way instead of relying on the range of unicode values? appreciate your help!

Comment: @Sai often it's better to implement whitelist validation instead of blacklist validation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49516025/1602555).

Comment: Ok, i agree. Thanks again Karol!