# Remove all graphical unicode characters from string

Tags: regex, perl

How can I remove all graphical unicode characters (emoji, symbols, flags, etc) from a string?

I have tried:

```
$text =~ s/[\x{0001F600}-\x{0001F64F}]|[\x{0001F300}-\x{0001F5FF}]|[\x{0001F680}-\x{0001F6FF}]|[\x{0001F1E0}-\x{0001F1FF}]|[\x{2600}-\x{26FF}]//g;
```

It removes some characters, but not all.

These characters are left untouched by regex:

What did I miss?

Comment: what do you want to *keep*?

Comment: Which chars fail exactly? A simple search for "regex remove emojis" presents many possible solutions so is there any reason that the existing Internet answers do not suit your needs?

Comment: I have edited my post to clarify the question. I want to keep latin and cyrillic non graphical characters only

Comment: Where does your string come from? If it is defined literally in source, you may need `use utf8;`. If it comes from STDIN or a file or socket, you may need to decode it from UTF-8, or set an `:encoding(UTF-8)` layer on the handle. And then make sure it is encoded back to UTF-8 for output.

Comment: @Grinnz, 'use utf8' pragma is set. String comes from CGI::Fast

Comment: @AlexStorm The CGI.pm and CGI::Fast modules do not decode parameters, so you need to do that. `my $param = decode 'UTF-8', scalar $cgi->param('foo');` with decode from [Encode](https://perldoc.pl/Encode).

Comment: See also http://blogs.perl.org/users/grinnz/2018/11/modern-perl-cgi.html

Comment: As an aside, `[a-c]|[e-f]` can be simplified to `[a-ce-f]`

Answer (score 0):

I am posting solution to my question. This is a perl-version of the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49516025/11638033)

Created a whitelist for:

- all numeric (p{N})
- letter (p{L})
- mark (p{M})
- punctuation (p{P})
- whitespace/separator (p{Z})
- other formatting (p{Cf}) and other characters above U+FFFF in Unicode (p{Cs}), and newline (\s) characters
- p{L} specifically includes the characters from other alphabets such as Cyrillic, Latin, Kanji, etc.

```
$text =~ s/[^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{P}\p{Z}\p{Cf}\p{Cs}]//g;
```

or, blacklist all special characters

```
$text =~ s/\p{So}//g;
```

Comment: You don't need to use alternation `|` inside a character class