# How to exclude a character from regular expression?

Tags: java

I want to replace all non words characters from a string but I need to check if the word has a hyphen in it but the replace will delete the hyphen .
is there a way to do that after I replace everything that is not a letter or do I have to check before replacing ?

this is my code

```
word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510006/remove-and-other-such-emojis-images-signs-from-java-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex, `[^\w-]` which means NOT(a [word character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) or `-`).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String word = "Hello :) Hi, How are you doing? The Co-operative bank is open 2day!";
        word = word.replaceAll("[^\\w-]", "").toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
hellohihowareyoudoingtheco-operativebankisopen2day
```

Note that a word character (i.e. `\w`) includes `A-Za-z0-9_`. If you want your regex to restrict only up to alphabets and hyphen, you should use `[^A-Za-z\-]`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String word = "Hello :) Hi, How are you doing? The Co-operative bank is open 2day!";
        word = word.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\-]", "").toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
hellohihowareyoudoingtheco-operativebankisopenday
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to check if the word has a hyphen in it but the replace will delete the hyphen

So check if there is a hyphen before you strip non-alpha characters.

```
if(word.contains("-")) {
    //do whatever
}
//remove non-alpha chars
```